# Bootstrap 4: Two menus one display and one active menu item

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have one big menu that I need to divide into *cols* for mobile and desktop.
So I put put around it:

```
<div class="col-xl-12 col-md-12 col-6 first-set-skills">
  Menu 1
</div>
<div class="col-xl-12 col-md-12 col-6 second-set-skills">
  Menu 2
</div>
```

The problem is that I need both of them to act as one menu. Selecting one item from either of these should only display one result and one active menu item. But because I separated the menus, they show two active items in the menu:

[image]

Is there a way to make them both act as one menu, even though they are separated by divs ?

---

Here is the JSFiddle: **https://jsfiddle.net/prozik/qLu9pfje/12/**

Here is the bootstrap documentation for the nav (vertical) I followed: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/

Here is the code:

```
<!-- menu 1 -->
<div class="col-xl-12 col-md-12 col-6">
  <div class="nav flex-column nav flex-column nav-pills" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
  <a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
  <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
  <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-messages-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-messages" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-messages" aria-selected="false">Messages</a>
  <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-settings-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-settings" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-settings" aria-selected="false">Settings</a>
</div>
</div>


<!-- menu 2 -->
<div class="col-xl-12 col-md-12 col-6">
   <div class="nav flex-column nav flex-column nav-pills"  role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-about-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-about" role="tab" aria-controls="v-about-home" aria-selected="true">About</a>
    <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-company-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-company" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-company" aria-selected="false">Company</a>
    <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-carreers-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-carreers" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-carreers" aria-selected="false">Careers</a>
    <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-location-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-location" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-location" aria-selected="false">Location</a>
  </div>
</div>



<div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="v-pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab"> Home content </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-profile-tab"> Profile  content</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-messages" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-messages-tab"> Message content </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-settings" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-settings-tab"> Settings  content</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-about" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-about-tab"> About  content</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-company" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-company-tab-tab"> Company  content</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-carreers" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-carreers-tab"> Carreers  content</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-location" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-location-tab"> Location  content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, this is easily possible.
If you are careful, you have an active class for each of your two menus. Eliminate one of them to fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a jQuery hack to get the desired output,

Add

```
var $ = jQuery;
$("#tabGroupTwo").children().click(function(e){
  $("#tabGroupOne").children().each(function(f){
    $(this).removeClass("active");
  });
});

$("#tabGroupOne").children().click(function(e){
  $("#tabGroupTwo").children().each(function(f){
    $(this).removeClass("active");
  });
})
```

And add id to `nav-pills` div. Check the snippet

```js
var $ = jQuery;
$("#tabGroupTwo").children().click(function(e){
  $("#tabGroupOne").children().each(function(f){
    $(this).removeClass("active");
  });
});

$("#tabGroupOne").children().click(function(e){
  $("#tabGroupTwo").children().each(function(f){
    $(this).removeClass("active");
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->

<div class="container">

  <!-- menu 1 -->
  <div class="col-xl-12 col-md-12 col-6">
    <div class="nav flex-column nav flex-column nav-pills" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical" id="tabGroupOne">
      <a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
      <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
      <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-messages-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-messages" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-messages" aria-selected="false">Messages</a>
      <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-settings-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-settings" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-settings" aria-selected="false">Settings</a>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- menu 2 -->
  <div class="col-xl-12 col-md-12 col-6">
    <div class="nav flex-column nav flex-column nav-pills" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical" id="tabGroupTwo">
      <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-about-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-about" role="tab" aria-controls="v-about-home" aria-selected="true">About</a>
      <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-company-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-company" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-company" aria-selected="false">Company</a>
      <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-carreers-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-carreers" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-carreers" aria-selected="false">Careers</a>
      <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-location-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-location" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-location" aria-selected="false">Location</a>
    </div>
  </div>



  <div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab"> Home content </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-profile-tab"> Profile content</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-messages" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-messages-tab"> Message content </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-settings" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-settings-tab"> Settings content</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-about" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-about-tab"> About content</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-company" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-company-tab-tab"> Company content</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-carreers" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-carreers-tab"> Carreers content</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-location" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-location-tab"> Location content</div>
  </div>

</div>
```